# Virtual environments issue on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'm stuck on an issue with virtualenv and hoping someone may be able to help.

I see this error when trying to create a virtual env: OSError: Command /Users/andy.smith/foo/bar/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2

I've tried clean up up my Python environment and reinstall [python](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install/osx/) and [virtualenv](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref), 
and tried fixes from similar questions but to no avail. Any help would is extremely welcome.

The full error is:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ virtualenv bar
New python executable in /Users/andy.smith/foo/bar/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/andy.smith/foo/bar/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/andy.smith/foo/bar/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
Looking in links: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 484, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 442, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 587, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 705, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 814, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 397, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 625, in send
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/hooks.py", line 31, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 189, in handle_401
    username = six.moves.input("User for %s: " % parsed.netloc)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 947, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 904, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 796, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/andy.smith/foo/bar/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `foo/` and `bar/` segments literally what you're seeing on your  machine, or have you sanitized the output for us?

Comment: In addition to Chris's question, are you using the system's python installation, or did you install your own copy of 2.7?

Comment: @Chris- That's 98% literal.

Comment: @AlphaTested - If i understand right, this should be using the brew version. Though I suspect something is referencing the System version or something outside the brew install.

Comment: Fixed! Two things I learned:
1. *virtualenv yo --no-download* gets around the issue
2. There was a dependency on an external resource with old login information.
Thanks to all for the help!